# How to trace dynamically loaded library calls with ltrace

Tags: c, trace, dlopen, dynamic-library, ltrace

I have a C program using dynamically loaded library to load plugins.
I would like to trace the library calls in order to debug the plugin's loading.

I looked at `ltrace`, but I can't seem to make it work:

Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    void *handle;
    double (*cosine)(double);
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    cosine = dlsym(handle, "cos");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling (and removing `PIE`, otherwise ltrace won't see anything):
`gcc main.c -pg -ldl -no-pie`

Running: `ltrace ./a.out`

Output

```
__monstartup(0x401170, 0x401431, 0x7fffe3875838, 0x7fffe3875838)                                                               = 0
__cxa_atexit(0x7f712aa98ba0, 0, 0, 0)                                                                                          = 0
malloc(4)                                                                                                                      = 0x76ea30
dlopen("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.s"..., 1)                                                                               = 0x76ea80
dlsym(0x76ea80, "cos")                                                                                                         = 0x7f712a8abd00
dlerror()                                                                                                                      = nil
printf("%f\n", -0.416147-0.416147
)                                                                                                      = 10
dlclose(0x76ea80)                                                                                                              = 0
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

As you can see, the call to `cos` was skipped.
How can I trace that with that arguments ?

I gave a try to [`uftrace`](https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace)

But again, It doesn't trace the `cos` call:

```
uftrace -a --libname --nest-libcall ./a.out
-0.416147
# DURATION     TID     FUNCTION
            [  8300] | main() {
   1.754 us [  8300] |   malloc@libc-2.31.so(4) = 0x15c6120;
 509.774 us [  8300] |   dlopen@libdl-2.31.so("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", RTLD_LAZY) = 0x7ff70ae4d090;
   2.140 us [  8300] |   dlsym@libdl-2.31.so(0x7ff70ae4d090, "cos") = 0x7ff70aa61d00;
   0.463 us [  8300] |   dlerror@libdl-2.31.so() = "NULL";
 332.451 us [  8300] |   printf@libc-2.31.so("%f\n") = 10;
   2.134 us [  8300] |   dlclose@libdl-2.31.so(0x7ff70ae4d090) = 0;
 958.926 us [  8300] | } /*
```

Which is surprising because on this [comment](https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace/issues/24#issuecomment-255277226) it looks like it works.

Running on Ubuntu 20.04

- ltrace: `0.7.3`
- uftrace: `0.9.3`

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a special flag `-x pattern` to force tracing of symbols in `dlopen`-ed libraries (the easiest would be `-x '*'`, see @nayana's answer for more details.)

Older versions of `ltrace` do not include the relevant patch from https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=537781 (follow link to timetobleed.com) so they can't trace `dlopen`-ed libs.

Comment: AFAIK `ltrace` does have the `-x` option in version 0.7.3, that reference on timetobleed.com uses version 0.5

Answer (score 6):

The [yugr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65452060/3876138) answer is most relevant in this case. However even when using ltrace with the patch the usage is not straight-forward.

The important part is to use `-x` option otherwise the symbols from library load via dlopen will not show. This fact is stated in [NEWS](https://gitlab.com/cespedes/ltrace/-/blob/master/NEWS#L339):

> *** Support tracing of symbols from libraries opened with dlopen
>
> These symbols are selected by -x.

Luckily we can set it to show all symbols matching our library address which is achieved by using special `glob` format described in ltrace man page.

My use case was to debug custom alsa-lib plugin which is loaded via dlopen:

```
# ltrace -x "@libdl.so.2" -x "*@libcustom.so" -f aplay -D custom test.wav
[pid 4183] snd_pcm_hw_params(0x5598dc8ce0, 0x7fe4d76fe0, 0xa3377eac3f8c3d00, 0 <unfinished ...>
[pid 4183] dlopen@libdl.so.2(0x5598dc5db0, 1, 0x5598dc8a4c, 0 <unfinished ...>
[pid 4183] _init@libdirac_dldsp.so(4, 0x7fe4d77858, 0x7fe4d77880, 0x7fa61ce0d8 <unfinished ...>
....
[pid 4183] dlsym@libdl.so.2(0x5598dc8ef0, 0x7fa65b1e48, 1, 0)                                                                                      = 0x7fa61cf890
[pid 4183] dl_descriptor@libcustom.so(0x7fa61cf890, 0, 0x7fa6627988, 1)                                                                       = 0x7fa61fe9e8
.....
[pid 4183] custom_lib_init@libcustom.so(0x7fe4d76770, 0x7fa61ffaf0, 0, 0 <unfinished ...>
[pid 4183] custom_init@libcustom.so(0x7fe4d76770, 1, 3, 0)                                                                                      = 0
....
```

Comment: Nice. Note that one can also do simply `-x '*'`.